# dylib dynamic library calling a dylib : Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: excel, vba, gcc, g++, dylib

Under mac os x with g++ from gcc-5.2 I am trying to do the following : create a dylib exporting a class defined by header `tmp8bis_dylib.h` and source `tmp8bis_dylib.cpp`, and then create another dylib out of a source file `tmp8bis.cpp` using and linking to the previous dylib. Header and sources are in the same directory. I compile as follows :

```
g++-5.2.0 -m32 -Wall -g -c ./tmp8bis_dylib.cpp
g++-5.2.0 -m32 -dynamiclib ./tmp8bis_dylib.o -o ./tmp8bis_dylib.dylib
g++-5.2.0 -m32 -Wall -g -c ./tmp8bis.cpp
g++-5.2.0 -m32 -dynamiclib ./tmp8bis.o -o ./tmp8bis.dylib
```

and get this :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "complex::cmodule(double, double)", referenced from:
      _mymodule in tmp8bis.o
  "complex::complex(double, double)", referenced from:
      _mymodule in tmp8bis.o
  "complex::~complex()", referenced from:
      _mymodule in tmp8bis.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Obviously, I tried to pass various include and library paths with `-I` and `-L` flags respectively, with the very same result... Any idea ?

Files are below :

For `tmp8bis_dylib.h` :

```
#ifndef TMP_8_BIS_DYLIB_H
#define TMP_8_BIS_DYLIB_H

class complex
{
public:
      double real;
      double imag;
public:
      complex();
      complex(double x);
      complex(double x,double y);
      double cmodule(double x, double y);
      ~complex();
};

#endif
```

For `tmp8bis_dylib.cpp` :

```
#include "./tmp8bis_dylib.h"
#include <math.h>

extern "C"
{
      complex::complex()
      {
            real = 0.0 ;
            imag = 0.0 ;
      }

      complex::complex(double x)
      {
            real = x ;
            imag = 0.0 ;
      }

      complex::complex(double x,double y)
      {
            real = x ;
            imag = y ;
      }

      double complex::cmodule(double x, double y)
      {
            double res = sqrt(x*x+y*y);
            return res ;
      }

      complex::~complex()
      {

      }
}
```

For `tmp8bis.cpp` :

```
#include <math.h>
#include "./tmp8bis_dylib.h"

extern "C"
{
      double mymodule(double x, double y)
      {
            complex z(x,y);
            double ret = z.cmodule(x,y);
            return ret;
      }
}
```

*Precision.* `-m32` is because I need 32 bits dylib because the final dylib will be plugged into excel 2011's (for mac) VBA, which is 32 bits.

**EDIT.** Following [Brett Hale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/906839/brett-hale)'s comment about [Apple's advises about dylibs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/DynamicLibraryDesignGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002013-SW19), I added

```
#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
```

after the `#include`'s from `tmp8bis.cpp`, and `EXPORT`'s for all its member functions, and compiled as follows :

```
g++-5.2.0 -m32 -Wall -g -c ./tmp8bis_dylib.cpp
g++-5.2.0 -m32 -dynamiclib ./tmp8bis_dylib.o  -fvisibility=hidden -o ./tmp8bis_dylib.dylib
```

did a `sudo cp ./tmp8bis_dylib.dylib /opt/lib/libtmp8bis_dylib.dylib` and then compiled :

```
g++-5.2.0 -m32 -Wall -g -c ./tmp8bis.cpp
g++-5.2.0 -m32 -dynamiclib ./tmp8bis.o -o ./tmp8bis.dylib -L/opt/lib
```

and got the same result as before... Nor did

```
g++-5.2.0 -m32 -dynamiclib ./tmp8bis.o -o ./tmp8bis.dylib -ltmp8bis_dylib.dylib
```

make my day.

Comment: You can't wrap C++ methods in `extern "C"`, since this changes the calling conventions - or at least the name mangling of the symbols. Why not just use [`<complex>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) for the `std::complex<double>` class?

Comment: I should have precised that my `complex` class was just an excuse for an example. How could I achieve what I want ? (Btw, I already used dylibs by linking to them and including their header files, so what I want to achieve is possible for sure, but, conditionaly to your comment, not possible with how I am trying to do it.

Comment: OS X [dynamic libraries](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/000-Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001908-SW1) guide.

Comment: @BrettHale Thx for the guide. Opted for the `#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))` without success, see edit of my question.

Comment: @BrettHale I finally managed to do it, and the `#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))` is completely useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without resorting to `#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))` or any `-fvisibility=hidden`

```
g++-5.2.0 -m32 -Wall -fpic -g -c ./tmp8bis_dylib.cpp
g++-5.2.0 -m32 -shared ./tmp8bis_dylib.o -o ./libtmp8bis_dylib.dylib
g++-5.2.0 -m32 -Wall -g -c ./tmp8bis.cpp
g++-5.2.0 -m32 -shared ./tmp8bis.o -o ./tmp8bis.dylib -L. -ltmp8bis_dylib
```

finally worked. I did not managed to succeed without `-fpic`, naming `libtmp8bis_dylib.dylib` and using `-ltmp8bis_dylib`.